# Search associative array and print corresponding value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dictionary like

```
UUU F
UUC F
CUU L
CUC L
UUA L
CUA L
UUG L
CUG L
AUU I
AUC I
AUA I
GUU V
GUC V
GUG V
GUA V
```

So Given a string I want to replace every 3 chars its respective char

I was thinking on using associative arrays:

```
    $d = array();
$d['UUU']='F';
$d['UUC']='F';
$d['UUA']='L';
$d['CUU']='L';
$d['GUC']='V';
$d['GUG']='V';
$d['GUA']='V';
$d['UUG']='L';
$d['CUG']='L';

$s = "UUAGUAUUG";
$temp="";
for($i=0; $i<strlen($s)+1; $i++){ 
    $temp .= $s[$i];
    if($i%3==0){
        echo $temp;
        echo array_search($temp, $d);
        $temp = "";
    }   
}



It should output LVL but have no success
```

Comment: `array_values` can accept only an array as parameter..you will get a warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_split`:

```
$s = 'UUAGUAUUG';
$split = str_split($s,3);
$translated = array();

foreach ($split as $bases) {
    /**
     * @ supresses warnings if the array index doesn't exist
     */
    $translated []= @$d[$bases];
}

echo join('',$translated);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work:

```
$temp = implode(array_map(function($a) { return $d[$a];}, str_split($s, 3)));
```

Comment: It is using the hash (the `$d[$a]` bit)

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution is:

```
<?php
$dict = array(
 'UUU' => 'F',
 'UUC' => 'F',
 'UUA' => 'L',
 'CUU' => 'L',
 'GUC' => 'V',
 'GUG' => 'V',
 'GUA' => 'V',
 'UUG' => 'L',
 'CUG' => 'L'
);

$before = "UUAGUAUUG";

$after = strtr($before, $dict);
```

Although you may be able to write a faster version that takes into account that you are replacing every three letters.

And I'm not 100% sure this will even work, given what kind of combinations can overlap over the 3-char barrier. Which leaves you with this rotten solution:

```
$after = str_replace('-', '',
  strtr(preg_replace('/[A-Z]{3}/', '\0-', $before), $dict));
```

Seriously, don't try this at home. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're testing at the wrong time.

Change `$i%3 == 0` to `$i%3 == 2`.

The reason here is that you have added to your temporary string first.  That means you immediately check a string of length 1 (`"U"`) and then clear it.  Then you go around for another 3 times and you get `"UAG"`, followed by `"UAU"`.  Neither of these are in your array.

What I don't understand is that you output the value of `$temp` each time this happens, so you should have picked up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to this:

```
for($i=0; $i<strlen($s)+1; $i++){ 
    $temp .= $s[$i];
    if(($i+1)%3==0){
        echo $d[$temp];
        $temp = "";
    }   
}
```

Your i value starts from 0. And array_values does not give the expected answer.